# google search url for search by image

Tags: image, google-search, google-image-search

I need to create a `search url` such that when clicked on a `image`, its url should be passed as a search parameter for `search by image` on google.

E.g. On clicking this image:

```
<img src = 'http:abc.com/image1.jpg'>
```

I need to pass this image url for `searching`.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer:

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=< http:abc.com/image1.jpg >
```